# How to test a ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I developed a `@KafkaListener` that is also marked with the `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` interface, using Spring Boot 2.0.6. I implemented the `onPartitionsAssigned` method, in which I rewind the offset of a fixed amount of time, let's say 60 seconds.

So far so good.

How can I test the above use case using the tools that Spring Kafka gives me? I supposed I need to start a Kafka broker (i.e., an `EmbeddedKafka`), then stopping the listener and then rebooting it again, to test that it read again the messages arrived in the last 60 seconds.

Can somebody help me? I googled a little, but I didn't find anything.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@KafkaListener` has an:

```
/**
 * The unique identifier of the container managing for this endpoint.
 * <p>If none is specified an auto-generated one is provided.
 * @return the {@code id} for the container managing for this endpoint.
 * @see org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)
 */
String id() default "";
```

attribute, so you can get an access to its `MessageListenerContainer` via mentioned `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`, which you can simply `@Autowired` into the test class based on Spring Testing Framework. Then, you can really `stop()` and `start()` that `MessageListenerContainer` in your test method.

Also pay attention how `@KafkaListener` has an `autoStartup()` attribute also.

Comment: But if you just want to unit test your listener, simply invoke it with a mock `Consumer` and verify it did what you expected.

Comment: @GaryRussell can you give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyRebalanceListener implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener {

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        long rewindTo = System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000;
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes = consumer.offsetsForTimes(partitions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(tp -> tp, tp -> rewindTo)));
        offsetsForTimes.forEach((k, v) -> consumer.seek(k, v.offset()));
    }

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So52973119ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void rebalanceListenerTests() {
        MyRebalanceListener listener = new MyRebalanceListener();
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer = mock(Consumer.class);
        AtomicLong expected = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60_000);
        given(consumer.offsetsForTimes(anyMap())).willAnswer(i -> {
            AtomicLong offset = new AtomicLong();
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes = new HashMap<>();
            Map<TopicPartition, Long> argument = i.getArgument(0);
            argument.forEach((k, v) -> {
                offsetsForTimes.put(k, new OffsetAndTimestamp(offset.incrementAndGet(), 0L));
                assertThat(v).isBetween(expected.get(), expected.get() + 1_000);
            });
            return offsetsForTimes ;
        });
        TopicPartition t1 = new TopicPartition("foo", 0);
        TopicPartition t2 = new TopicPartition("foo", 1);
        List<TopicPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        partitions.add(t1);
        partitions.add(t2);
        listener.onPartitionsAssigned(consumer, partitions);
        verify(consumer).seek(t1, 1);
        verify(consumer).seek(t2, 2);
    }

}
```