# Spring Kafka - access offsetsForTimes to start consuming from specific offset

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a fairly straightforward Kafka consumer:

```
MessageListener<String, T> messageListener = record -> {

    doStuff( record.value()));
  };

  startConsumer(messageListener);


protected void startConsumer(MessageListener<String, T> messageListener) {
ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, T> container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(
    consumerFactory(this.brokerAddress, this.groupId),
    containerProperties(this.topic, messageListener));

   container.start();
}
```

I can consume messages without any issue.
Now, I have the requirement to `seek` from a specific offset based on the result of a call to `offsetsForTimes` on the Kafka Consumer.

I understand that I can `seek` to a certain position using the `ConsumerSeekAware` interface:

```
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments,
        ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

      assignments.forEach((t, o) -> callback.seek(t.topic(), t.partition(), ?????));
}
```

The problem now, is that I do not have access to the Kafka Consumer inside the callback, therefore I have no way to call `offsetsForTimes`.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` to do the initial seeks (introduced in 2.0).

The current version is 2.2.0.

[How to test a ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973119/how-to-test-a-consumerawarerebalancelistener/52976119#52976119)

Comment: I added a link to another answer.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm Using apache Kafka consumer and my offsetfortimes method returns only few partitions offset positions though all partitions are assigned.. I check ConsumerRebalanceListner.onPartitionsAssigned method receives all partitions but when I do offsetfortimes for all partitions inside the onPartitionsAssigned method it returns only the 1 or 2 partitions offset positions. Do u have any idea on the pblm? I posted a question on this too.

Comment: It's best not to ask new questions in comments, but I [found your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200574). In future if you comment on an old answer, add a link to the new question.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Sure will do in future.