# Spring Integration to read message from Kafka topic based on timestamp

Tags: spring-integration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-integration-dsl

While using spring `kafka` I am able to read the messages from the topic based on time stamp with the below code -

```
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                if (flag) {
                    Map<TopicPartition, Long> query = new HashMap<>();
                    query.put(new TopicPartition(kafkaTopic, 0), millisecondsFromEpochToReplay);

                    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> result = consumer.offsetsForTimes(query);
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        records = ConsumerRecords.empty();
                    }

                    result.entrySet().stream()
                            .forEach(entry -> consumer.seek(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().offset()));

                    flag = false;
                }
```

How can the same functionality be achieved using **spring integration DSL** - with `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`?
How can we set the Integration Flows and read message from topic based on the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the adapter's listener container with a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` and perform the lookup/seeks when the partitions are assigned.

**EDIT**

Using Spring Boot (but you can configure the container however you create the container)...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=so54664761
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54664761Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54664761Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so54664761", "foo");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so54664761", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = container(containerFactory);
        return IntegrationFlows.from(new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container))
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {

        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = containerFactory.createContainer("so54664761");
        container.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                System.out.println("Partitions assigned - do the lookup/seeks here");
            }

        });
        return container;
    }

}
```

and

```
Partitions assigned - do the lookup/seeks here
GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@2f5b2297, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=so54664761, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1550241100112}]
```

Comment: Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973119/how-to-test-a-consumerawarerebalancelistener/52976119#52976119).

Comment: Thanks @Gary, I am new to this so need help on understanding how can we inject the ConsumerAwareRebalance Listener in Spring Integration DSL , my flow looks like

Comment: See the edit to my answer; it uses Boot's auto-configured container factory, but you can add the listener to the container properties however you create the container.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your help. If we want to have multiple consumer within the same consumer group should we set the concurrency level of ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer? How can we set multiple consumers in the above configuration?

Comment: When using Spring Boot, `spring.kafka.consumer.concurrency=5`; when creating containers yourself `container.setConcurrency(5)`.