# Spring Kafka Consumer, rewind consumer offset to go back 'n' records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using "programmatic" way of consuming messages from Kafka topic using `org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`

I'm wondering if there's a "spring" way of rewinding offsets for a specific partitions of a topic to go back 'n' messages?

Would like to know the cleanest way of doing this (programmatically and not using the CLI).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the offsets during application startup, use a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` and perform the seeks on the consumer when the partitions are assigned; you can find the current offset(s) by calling `Consumer.position()`.

If you want to arbitrarily rewind the partitions at runtime, have your listener implement `ConsumerSeekAware` and grab a reference to the `ConsumerSeekCallback`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584233/how-to-get-kafkalistener-consumer/56584668#56584668) for an example of using `ConsumerSeekAware`.

`ConsumerSeekAware` also has `onIdleContainer()` which will be called when no records have been received during `idleEventInterval`; that callback provides you with the current offsets.

Comment: Thanks for that - Is there anyway I could use the ConsumerSeekAware programatically? (ie without using @KafkaListener annotation). My use case here is using dynamic message listeners.

Comment: Any `MessageListener` can implement `ConsumerSeekAware`; it's not just for `KafkaListener`. The container knows nothing about its listener.