# Sping Boot Service consume kafka messages on demand

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have requirement where need to have a Spring Boot Rest Service that a client application will call every 30 minutes and service is to return

1. number of latest messages based on the number specified in query param e.g. http://messages.com/getNewMessages?number=10 in this case should return 10 messages
2. number of messages based on the number and offset specified in query param e.g. http://messages.com/getSpecificMessages?number=5&start=123 in this case should return 5 messages starting offset 123.

I have simple standalone application and it works fine. Here is what I tested and would lke some direction of incorporating it in the service.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create kafka consumer
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-first-consumer-group");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, args[0]);

        Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

        // subscribe to topic
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("test"));
        consumer.poll(0);

        //get to specific offset and get specified number of messages
        for (TopicPartition partition : consumer.assignment())
            consumer.seek(partition, args[1]);

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000));

        System.out.println("Total Record Count ******* : " + records.count());      

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + record.value());
            System.out.println("Message offset: " + record.offset());           
            System.out.println("Message: " + record.timestamp());
            Date date = new Date(record.timestamp());
            Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            System.out.println("Message date: " + format.format(date));
        }
        consumer.commitSync();
```

As my consumer will be on-demand wondering in Spring Boot Service how I can achieve this. Where do I specify the properties if I put in application.properties those get's injected at startup time but how do i control MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG at runtime. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953784/spring-kafka-consumer-rewind-consumer-offset-to-go-back-n-records/56954463) and the answer with code example is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56953784/spring-kafka-consumer-rewind-consumer-offset-to-go-back-n-records/56954463).
Both written by the excellent Gary Russell, the main or one of the main person behind Spring Kafka.

TL;DR:

> If you want to arbitrarily rewind the partitions at runtime, have your
> listener implement ConsumerSeekAware and grab a reference to the
> ConsumerSeekCallback.

Answer (score 0):

MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG only impact your kafka-client return the records to your spring service, it will never reduce the bytes that the consumer poll from kafka-server

[image]

see the above picture, no matter your start offset = 150 or 190, kafka server will return the whole data from (offset=110, offset=190), kafka server even didn't know how many records return to consumer, he only know the byte size = (220 - 110)

so i think you can control the record number by yourself,currently it is controlled by the kafka client jar, they are both occupy your jvm local memory

Comment: where can I put the configurations in the spring service.